# PSFTP open for write: failure

Tags: sftp, putty

I am uploading a file from a collection of different servers to one data server. I am using psftp and one out of 20+ servers is producing a permissions problem.

```
Remote working directory is /
psftp> cd Remote_Directory\ 
Remote directory is now /Remote_Directory/
psftp> put C:\folders\containing\file\FILE.zip    
/Remote_Directory/: open for write: failure
psftp> quit
```

It appears like a permissions issue on the remote directory, however, why am I only getting the issue on one server? The batch is identical on all of the 20+ servers.

Comment: It's not clear what this has to do with programming. Are you developing/modifying this `psftp` tool or just using it?

Answer (score 7):

PUT command expects a file name at the end of the destination location.

Please try the following code

```
put C:\folders\containing\file\FILE.zip /Remote_Directory/FILE.zip
```

Answer (score 0):

The path in the error message is an exact path to the remote file the psftp tried to create. See `outfname` in below code snippet:

```c
req = fxp_open_send(outfname,
                        SSH_FXF_WRITE | SSH_FXF_CREAT | SSH_FXF_TRUNC,
                        &attrs);
...
printf("%s: open for write: %s\n", outfname, fxp_error());
```

As the path is obviously not correct (lacks file name), it seems that psftp got confused somehow. I believe it's likely due to wrong (back)slash you have used in the `cd` command.

Try `cd Remote_Directory/`.

Comment: I had tried cd Remote_Directory/ as well as cd Remote_Directory and i get the same results. 

`Remote working directory is /
psftp> cd Remote_Directory/ 
Remote directory is now /Remote_Directory/
psftp> put C:\folders\containing\file\FILE.zip    
/Remote_Directory/: open for write: failure
psftp> quit`

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it's a permission issue on the remote server, i.e. the account you are using to log on doesn't have the write permission for the remote folder.